# jQuery detect if on ipad/iphone (mobile safari) and use jQuery touch dialog instead of regular jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've built a web application using jquery ui. I never even tried to make it compatable on an ipad until recently, everything works fine on the ipad except the jquery ui dialogs. I've come across jquery touch and I like the 'dialog' component.

How would I detect if the browser is safari mobile and use the jQuery touch dialogs instead of the standard jquery ui dialog? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have something like this, although it's rather crude. Someone might argue that you would go for feature detection rather than agent detection, but sometimes it's not that clear cut:

```
$.extend({
        isIpad: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i) != null;
        }
});

$.isIpad();
```

Comment: I'd use it, I might even throw a />_< in there, too.